# Why is RegisterClientScriptInclude causing multiple page loads?

Tags: asp.net, ascx, clientscriptmanager

After much banging of the head and manual line-by-line code removal, I have figured out that a `RegisterClientScriptInclude` call inside an ASCX web control is causing multiple page_load events to fire.  This only happens when the ASCX is included on some pages, but not others.

Removing this line of code causes the double-postback to stop:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
    Page.GetType(), 
    "[SCRIPTNAME]", 
    "[SCRIPTFILE].js")
```

I also tried this without including `Page.GetType()`, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

That line of code shouldn't be causing multiple page loads...  There's probably something else going on...  I would turn on Tracing at the page level and throw some Trace.Warn statements in to see what's going on...

But I'm not a big fan of the Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude() method and find that it's usually easier just to include the .js file in the parent aspx page...  It's a very mild performance hit if that .js file isn't needed on a particular page...

Comment: Well the conditional loading of the JS file is more about security based access to features, not about performance.

Comment: Interesting...  Maybe bubbling up to the calling page and including the script there would work...  but I would have to look at all your code to see what's going on...